# How to set X-Axis value Fix for X-Y line chart

Tags: c#, charts

I can set the chart into the Excel but when I draw a chart using c# the X-Axis value is not have perfect gap.

like if i set

```
serie1.Points.AddXY(0.003247884, 16808.99);
serie1.Points.AddXY(0.006495768, 16794.35);
serie1.Points.AddXY(0.009743652, 16783.6);
serie1.Points.AddXY(0.012991540, 16767.22);
serie1.Points.AddXY(0.016239420, 16760.1);
serie1.Points.AddXY(0.019487300, 16748.68);
serie1.Points.AddXY(0.022735190, 16729.46);
```

I want X-serices 1.00000 , 2.00000 , 3.00000 , an so on...

in Excel the chart is 
[image]

but in C# desktop application

[image]

Comment: Okay, next try: Why do you use AddXY() if you don't want the X-value? What about using AddY() (and maybe storing the datapoints separately)?

Comment: It's just a matter of conveniently defining `Minimum`, `Maximum` and `Interval`, for both X and Y axes. Now, the excel image and the corresponding data you posted are completely unrelated, so don't expect chart images to match.

Answer (score 2):

To set the interval:

```
 chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
 chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 0.01; // Whatever you like
```

To "ignore" the X-Values and make them 1,2,3,4,etc.:

```
chart1.Series[0].IsXValueIndexed = true;
```

Comment: Thanks , but its's not working . because my value  between 0 to 1 and on x-axis its show me that  point value which i set i just want 1 , 2 ,3 , .... on x-axis .

Comment: Ah, I think I've got it now.

Comment: again thanks but still give me the same issues , because X-axis value is  0.003247884,  
0.006495768,  
0.009743652, 
0.012991540,
0.016239420,
0.019487300 ,
0.022735190,
 but i do not want that on x-axis i want incremental value with serices

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean the axis intervals should increment by 1?.. Set the AxisX interval to 1

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;    
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but its will set the Interval value for the X-Axis value ... Ie. if my X-Axis is 1, 2, 3, 4, ,5 ,6,7 and then i set AxisX.Minimum = 0 and AxisX.Interval = 2 , then on my Chart X-Axis values are 1,3,5,7 .. but my original X-Axis value are   0.003247884, 0.006495768, 0.009743652, 0.012991540, 0.016239420, 0.019487300 , 0.022735190 , 1.12562562 , 1.13565895 , etc and then i want to set the X-Axis to 1, 2, 3 , 4 ....